# How do I query data by indexedDB like %string% sql?

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

Sorry for my poor English.

I have found and read these answers:

- [Indexeddb: search using
  wildcards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9791219/indexeddb-search-using-wildcards)
- [IndexedDB Fuzzy Search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7086180/indexeddb-fuzzy-search)

I know the query in indexedDB like this:

> var range = IDBKeyRange.bound(string, string + '\uffff');

For example, there is a data name 'wake up', I can found it by the keyword 'wake', but how can I found it by the keyword 'up'?

Comment: I think the original indexedDB can not do complexly fuzzy search, so I change to lokiJs. Maybe I can save the data in a string and search the keyword by a function. But it will be a huge code work. So finally I use the lokiJs which has evolved several mechanisms for querying the database. You can have a look: => [link](https://rawgit.com/techfort/LokiJS/master/jsdoc/tutorial-Query%20Examples.html)