# How do I get the results of an indexedDb request outside the scope of its callback

Tags: javascript, html, indexeddb

I have a form with a input box that I want to auto-complete with values from a IndexedDb objectStore, this works with two over positioned input boxes. I works fine with a simple array but I want to put it to work with the values from a objectStore.
For this I have to put the values available out of the transaction so I can loop through them in the auto-complete function.

1- How can I get the results out of the transaction into a object available in the rest of the code?

2- Is my loop syntax ok "results.value.name.length" (name is my objectStore index) to work with the resultant object?

Getting the IndexedDb objects through a cursor:

```
var results = [];

var openDbRequest = indexedDB.open(DB_NAME);

openDbRequest.onsuccess = function (e) {
    var db = e.target.result;
    var tran2 = db.transaction("store");
    tran2.objectStore("store").openCursor().onsuccess = function(e) {
        var cursor = e.target.result;
        if (cursor) {
            results = cursor;
            cursor.continue();  
        };
    };                                      
};
```

The autocomplete function

```
var auto = "";
var auto_disp = "";

function getName(results) {
    var input = document.forms['myform'].name.value;
    var len = input.length;
    if (input.length) {
        for (i=0; i<results.value.name.length; i++){            
            if (results.value.name[i].substr(0,len).toLowerCase() == input.toLowerCase()){
                auto_disp = input + results.value.name[i].substr(len);
                auto = results.value.name[i];
                break;
            }
        }
    }
document.forms['myform'].auto_name.value = auto_disp;
}

function setName() {
 document.forms['myform'].name.value = auto;
 hideAuto();
}

function hideAuto() {
 document.forms['myform'].auto_name.value = "";
}
```

The HTML form:

```
<div style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 200px; z-index: 1;">
 <input type="text" name="name" style="background-color: #fff; border: 1px solid #999; width: 200px; padding: 2px" disabled />
</div>

<div style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 200px; z-index: 2;">
 <input autocomplete="off" type="text" name="auto_name" style="background: none; color:#39f; border: 1px solid #999; width: 200px; padding: 2px" onfocus="getName()"onkeyup="getName()" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) {setName();};"/>
</div>
```

UPDATE: Tried a different chaining, now I get the cursor but there's something wrong with the loop, I'm not getting the auto-completion.

```
openDbRequest.onsuccess = function (e) {
    var db = e.target.result;

    var tran2 = db.transaction("store");
    tran2.objectStore("store").openCursor().onsuccess = function(e) {

        var cursor = e.target.result;
        if (cursor) { 
            var input = document.forms['myform'].country.value; //the inputted value
            var len = input.length;
            if (input.length) {
                for (i=0; i<cursor.length; i++){            
                    if (cursor.value.nome[i].substr(0,len).toLowerCase() == input.toLowerCase()){
                        auto_disp = input + cursor.value.nome[i].substr(len);
                        auto = cursor.value.nome[i];
                        break;                              
                    }
                }   
            }
            document.forms['myform'].auto_name.value = auto_disp;
            cursor.continue();  
        }   
    };
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use it outside the transaction scope, just add it to a variable

```
var results = [];
var openDbRequest = indexedDB.open(DB_NAME);
openDbRequest.onsuccess = function (e) {
    var db = e.target.result;
    var tran2 = db.transaction("store");
    tran2.objectStore("store").openCursor().onsuccess = function(e) {
         var cursor = e.target.result;
         if (cursor) {
              results.push(cursor.value) 
              cursor.continue();
         };
    };
};
```

After this you van iterate over the results object, and the transaction scope will close once all data is retrieved.

Comment: Ok, I thought so. How can I measure the number of objects, 'results.length'? I wasn't getting the loop to work.

Comment: results.length should provide you the number of elements in the collection, keep in mind that you can only start to iterate te collection once you retrieved the data for the indexeddb. I think that is your problem

Comment: yep... I'm getting "TypeError: results is undefined", any idea in how to surpass this, I will be calling the getName() function every time the user types a letter so the transaction shouldn't be inside it and if I nest it inside the transaction's oncomplete() it will be called undefined.

Comment: I'm trying to disable the input box and do something like this:     tran2.oncomplete = function(e) { document.forms['myForm'].name.disabled = false; getName(results); };

Comment: I think I'm back to point zero, the cursor or the results are always available inside the transaction or the oncomplete() but not outside

Comment: "TypeError: results is undefined" --> did you declare your results variable like this "results = []" before calling the code to retrieve data

Comment: yes, above the indexedDB.open(), I can access the data inside the transaction but not outside

Comment: Sorry, I was using "var results = [];", I can access the data now. just a last question Kristof, what are the properties of this object? my Indexes are there but calling "results.value.myIndex", "results.item.myIndex" or "results.myIndex" are not working.

Comment: if you are in the loop it is the following: results[i].myIndex

Comment: yep, just figured it out "results[i].name" I was still thinking of cursors :), thanks Kristof!