# How to search indexeddb for a string

Tags: javascript, search, indexeddb

I am trying to set up a search feature on my site, i'm trying to find IndexedDB code for

`SELECT "column" FROM "table" WHERE "column" LIKE "%keyword%"`

i found a solution in [IndexedDB Fuzzy Search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7086180/indexeddb-fuzzy-search)

```
db.transaction(['table'], 'readonly')
    .objectStore('table')
    .openCursor(IDBKeyRange.bound(keyword, keyword + '\uffff'), 'prev')
    .onsuccess = function (e) {
        e || (e = event);
        var cursor = e.target.result;
        if (cursor) {
            console.log(cursor.value.column);
            cursor.continue();
        }
    };
```

but how can i find "%keyword%" instead of "%keyword" ?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how this all works so I'm just guessing, but what about `IDBKeyRange.bound('\uffff' + keyword, keyword + '\uffff')` ?

Comment: it doesnt work, return error `DataError: DOM IDBDatabase Exception 0`

Comment: possible duplicate of [IndexedDB Fuzzy Search](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7086180/indexeddb-fuzzy-search)

Comment: @Josh no, I don't think it's a duplicate. The OP clearly mentions what is different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing similar to SQL WHERE in IndexedDB.

I would loop through the table/object store values and see if the current cursor column contains the keyword:

```
var keyword = "foo";
var transaction = db.transaction("table", "readwrite");
var objectStore = transaction.objectStore("table");
var request = objectStore.openCursor();
request.onsuccess = function(event) {
    var cursor = event.target.result;
    if (cursor) {
        if (cursor.value.column.indexOf(keyword) !== -1) {                
            console.log("We found a row with value: " + JSON.stringify(cursor.value));
        }  

        cursor.continue();          
    }
};
```

Comment: this is slow, should it be better with index and index value range?