# IndexedDB search a word from a middle of record values in table

Tags: javascript, typescript, indexeddb

I'm using indexed-db with dexie.js in Angular 11 project.

I want to do search like if a word matches in a middle of email or full_name field's value then I want those records.

I got [IndexedDB Fuzzy Search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7086180/indexeddb-fuzzy-search) but it is not working in my case. It gives me error like

`db.transaction(...).objectStore is not a function.`

How can I do search, is there any other way?